# Python Scraping from Chicago Reporter

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Python to scrape info from this site (http://projects.chicagoreporter.com/settlements/search/cases).

I'm trying to get the case number, case payment, location of incident, and date of incident.

So far, I have only been able to get the case number.
Here's my code to try to get the case payment, but it doesn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://projects.chicagoreporter.com/settlements/search/cases'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'case-payment'}):
    href = "http://projects.chicagoreporter.com/settlements/search/cases"
    title = link.string
    print(title)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you got the case number as the site content is pretty much 99 percent dynamically created?

Comment: `import requests`  
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`  
`url = 'http://projects.chicagoreporter.com/settlements/search/cases'`  
`source_code = requests.get(url)`  
`plain_text = source_code.text`  
`soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")`  
`for link in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'case'}):`  
    `href = "http://projects.chicagoreporter.com/settlements/search/cases"`  
    `title = link.string`  
    `print(title[12:])`

Comment: Hi Padraic,  
That's my code above (not sure how to get the code onto new lines in the comments. Does the fact that it is dynamically created mean that I will have trouble scraping it the conventional way?

Comment: yes the content is loaded using js, if you view the actual source you can see the templates and how it gets created